# Xamarin Forms iOS how to bring app to foreground - other apps do it

Tags: ios, forms, xamarin, foreground

I'm working on my Xamarin Forms app. It needs to bring itself to the foreground once its been backgrounded using location services (background mode) after a while. How can this be achieved?

I notice other apps do it in the app store.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `bring itself to the foreground`? Do you mean the app open automatically once its been backgrounded using location services?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` to achieve this.

In the apple document https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati it writes:

> **If you start this service and your app is subsequently terminated, the system automatically relaunches the app into the background if a
>   new event arrives.** In such a case, the options dictionary passed to
>   the application(*:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) and
>   application(*:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) methods of your app
>   delegate contains the key location to indicate that your app was
>   launched because of a location event. Upon relaunch, you must still
>   configure a location manager object and call this method to continue
>   receiving location events. When you restart location services, the
>   current event is delivered to your delegate immediately. In addition,
>   the location property of your location manager object is populated
>   with the most recent location object even before you start location
>   services.

After relaunch, you can do something in `FinishedLaunching` in AppDelegate:

```
 public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.
            // If not required for your application you can safely delete this method

            if (launchOptions.ContainsKey(UIApplication.LaunchOptionsLocationKey))
            {
                // do something here after the app awaked
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: My app will recieve location updates and publish to ui. User can also choose to switch out the app at which point the app runs in the background because of location services background mode. When the destination has been reached, and if my app was backgrounded by User, the app should bring itself to the front through code in active running mode.

Comment: Well,I don't think you can achieve this in an iOS system.

Comment: What about push notifications?

Comment: Sure, you can fire a local notification when the destination has been reached.And your app will enter foreground after the user tap the notification.But there is a problem that if you app is terminated, your local notification will not be fired at that time.

Comment: Thank you jack hua. I'll think about the app termination. It really depends on what criteria the app gets terminated, but I thought if you register for location background mode your app wouldn't get terminated, and if in any circumstances it did the location update event would set the app state to backgrounded from terminated?